# Looking for the correct way to use Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with Jersey Client Web Service Call

Tags: java, spring, connection, threadpoolexecutor, jersey-client

I am working on a web application and one of the requirements is to make a call to an external web service which is being done through a Jersey Client. Now I want to make this web service api call in a separate thread so that the UI does not get blocked waiting for the WS response. I also want to be able to just log the response returned by the web service call and I will not be using the response in any business logic.
For this purpose I have created a spring managed bean which will hold a reference to spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. The configuration is as follows:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>

<bean id="updateEmailSubscriptionClient" class="com.myorg.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

`MyClass` has an inner class which implements runnable and is used to spawn the thread that will do the actual webservice call and log the response, all done asynchronously so that the UI is not blocked. `MyClass` looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Client jClient; //The jersey client
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public MyClass(TaskExecutor taskExecutor){
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
        ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();

        //Initialize jersey client config here ...

        jClient = Client.create(cc);

    }

    public void makeWSCall(){

        //Do some stuff

        taskExecutor.execute(new WorkerClass());
    }

    private class WorkerClass implements Runnable{

        void run(){
            WebResource webResource = jClient.resource(myResource);

            //Setup webresource here with headers, mime etc....

            try{
                String resp = webResource.post(String.class);

                //Log the response here ...

            }catch(UniformInterfaceException e){

                 //Do something ...
            }

        }  

    }
}
```

As can be seen from the code above, the attempt is to put the jersey client call to the WS in the run method of `WorkerClass` which implements `Runnable`.The public method `makeWSCall` will then have the `taskExecutor` execute a new `WorkerClass` object whenever it is called. My questions/concerns are as folllows:

1. Is this a good way to go about the problem at hand and will it perform well for multiple clients using our public domain website?
2. I have not given any destroy method for `taskExecutor` in the Spring config file. Is it necessary?
3. What would happen if the `run()` method of `WorkerClass` would throw an exception? Does that thread become available from within the pool again?
4. Any other concerns or better ideas.

Please note that I tried using Jersey's `AsyncWebResource` but I still have to obtain the response from the Future object that is returned on a post which would still block the UI. Also, we are using a very old version of jersey client (1.0.2) and some of the newer features might not be available in it. Upgrading to a newer version is currently out of scope for the project.

**EDIT**
I read about @Async annotation in Spring and I think thats a better option than using an inner class that implements runnable. I think the way to go about it would be to transfer the code in `WorkerClass` to `makeWSCall`, annotate `makeWSCall` with @Async, make the necessary changes in the spring configuration file. However, what happens if another executor is defined in the application context. How would Spring know which executor to run my @Async method in?

**EDIT**
I ended up using @Async annotation which is working fine. Another concern is closing connections. How can I assure connection is closed after response is returned. I could call `getEntity` on the `ClientResponse` object which would ensure that connection is closed (according to jersey documentation). However, if there is an exception in `getEntity` or even when I do the actual post request on my webresource, would connection still be closed or do I have to do it explicitly? In my version of jersey there is no `close()` method for `ClientResponse`. How should I go about closing the connection on exception?